# How to prevent users to open same page more than once at a time

Tags: php, mysql, web

On my website people earn points by seeing a page. They get 1 point for each second they keep the page open (the page keeps rotating Advertisements).

Some people have started exploiting this by opening that page multiple times all together and hence are earning more points! for example if the user open the page 10 times then he is earning 10 points for each second. I don't want them to earn more than 1 point per second.

**How can I prevent the users from opening that page more than once at the same time?**

Thanks in advance.
note : My website is php based.

Comment: I there any log in mechanism ? If so allow user to log in only once by adding some table to database with information if user is log in or not.

Comment: You may set a cookie or a variable in seesion of user for each page. And in each page check that variable. If set redirect him or do what you want. If no, open the page!

Comment: You can't prevent them from opening the same page more than once, but you can prevent them from getting multiple points for it. How does your current point system work?

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra - What if they disable cookies?

Comment: I guess using session here would be great!

Comment: @deceze - I just want to redirect them to a page saying "You are not allowed to run multiple instances of this page" or something like that. my system works on sql database and the rotator shows each advert for 30 seconds. The advertiser who pays more gets his advert shown first.

Comment: and if they disable cookies, just refuse to give any points

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra - A session in my website starts when the users logs in. Can I have 2 sessions open at the same time?

Comment: I am not really familiar with cookies, Can you please give me an example. @mvp

Comment: No , U just need to assign a value in session. And you can use it anywhere!

Comment: Can you please give em an example?

Comment: How will the session destroy if the users abruptly exits ?

Comment: How to you upload the points? each second the user is logged in the page you throw a UPLOAD query? Or do you save the total ammount somewhere and upload it each minute?

Comment: I upload the pints after a timer of 30 seconds, but the timer doesn't depend on my sql database, it is just a timer on that page.

Comment: hmm I'm afraid that's the problem then. There should be some control between the page the user sees and the final update to the database. That way this control script could detect more than 30 points per 30s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the time when the page is opened to the database. Whenever the page is opened check if the difference b/w that time and current time is less than xx seconds then redirect the user. If the difference is more than xx seconds then update that time.

Comment: But this can be exploided too! They just need to wait a few minutes/seconds. And what happens if the user opens that page, closes it directly and open's it again. He will be redirected too..?!

Comment: @Benedikt Mokroß - The time is updated every time the user gets point so even if they reopen after a few minutes, they would be caught. If the users opens it again just after closing then he would also be redirected and on the redirected page it would be written what happened and the user would automatically be redirected to the earlier page after a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

I have on easy but not reliable way in mind:

Set a Sessionvar like

```
$_SESSION['user_already_on_page'] = true;
```

Now you can check for this variable and return an error page or something like that.

```
if($_SESSION['user_already_on_page'])
{
    //maybe the user has left unexpected. to workaround this we have to check
    //for the last db entry. Examplecode:
    $query = mysql_query($_db,'SELECT LastUpdated FROM Pointstable WHERE U_Id = $uid');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if((time()-$row['LastUpdated']) < 5)
    {
        die("You are already on this page!");  
    }
    //$_SESSION['user_already_on_page'] is set but the last update is older than 5 sec
    //it seems, that he unexpectedly lost connection or something like that.
}
```

To unset this variable you could fire an AJAX-Script on pageclose that unsets this variable.
So your *unsetonpage.ajax.php* could look like this:

```
<?php $_SESSION['user_already_on_page'] = false;?>
```

And your JS-Part (using jquery):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(eventObject) {
    $.ajax({url:'./ajax/unsetonpage.ajax.php',type:'GET'});
});
```

This should work.

Comment: If the user exits abruptly, for example if his internet gets disconnected, then will he be able to open that page again?

Comment: @Max Unhappily not. But you could workaround that with checking for the last DB-Entry. Like `if($_SESSION['user_already_on_page']) {<check if last entry older than XX sec>}`. If the last entry is older than xx sec the user can continue visiting that site.

Comment: I added the time when the page is opened to the database. if the difference b/w that time and current time is less than xx seconds then i redirect the users. my problem has been fixed :)

Comment: @Max but this can be exploided too! They just need to wait a few minutes. And what happens if the user opens that page, closes it directly and open's it again. He will be redirected too..?!

Answer (score 0):

```
//--- You make session in startup called (my_form)
if (!empty($_SESSION['my_form'])) 
{
    if ($_SESSION['my_form']== basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))
    {
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['my_form']= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['my_form']= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```